# How can I have my bash script create a new line?

Tags: bash

I googled how to have bash write to a new line and tried it, but it's still writing to my file as a single line. Here's the command I used in my script:

**ud.sh**

```
echo -e "jira.node.id = node$RANDOM \ jira.shared.home = /var/sharedhome" | tee -a /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/cluster.properties
```

When I looked online it said to use -e and a '\' to write to a new line, however, after running this script, this is what the `cluster.properties` file currently looks like:

```
jira.node.id = node12146 \ jira.shared.home = /var/sharedhome
```

How can I make it so it writes to a new line- so the file looks like this?

```
jira.node.id = node12146
jira.shared.home = /var/sharedhome
```

Comment: Use `\n`, not just `\ `.

Comment: See ["How to add new lines when using echo"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219268/how-to-add-new-lines-when-using-echo/219274#219274). In short, `\n` ought to work, but different versions of `echo` behave differently, so you may have to try a few things to find one that works.

Comment: `printf` is another option:  `printf "%s\n%s\n" "jira.node.id = node$RANDOM" "jira.shared.home = /var/sharedhome" >> /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/cluster.properties`

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "line one" "line two" ...`